# How to create extendable jmeter test plans?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, test-architecture

We have received 20 jmeter test plans, each testing one endpoint, which we need to run as part of AzureDevops pipeline. On some tests we need to pass parameters and others we don't.

My idea was to create a powershell script called from a pipeline that loops through the directories and runs a test, waits until finished and then runs the next test. When we develop a new endpoint we just create a new test plan and save it in the appropriate folder and the powershell script will include it next time we loop through tests.

Reading about Jmeter, it seems like the correct way run tests in sequence, is to create one Testplan that with all the tests, with Thread Groups and then set the plan to run consecutively. I could rewrite all the tests be in one file, but then adding new tests would involve editing the test plan instead of just dropping new test file in our tests directory.

My question then is, how to create extendable jmeter test plans?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution with powershell makes sense.

Another idea is to use [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin) which automatically runs all the scripts it finds under `src/test/jmeter` folder relative to [pom.xml](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) file.

You can also [pass parameters](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Modifying-Properties#5) via Maven pom.xml file.

More information: [How to Use the JMeter Maven Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin)